# Why can't reputation be earned any more on MSO?

Tags: discussion

So why? It could be done so as you earn reputation both on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's how Meta works -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: We don't want to give rep on SO just because someone posted a funny  picture of a unicorn on meta.

Comment: I would go even further: not only no reputation, but _not even votes_.

Comment: @Final Why no votes?..

Comment: @nicael: because it generates negativity in the community in my opinion. See, you got 10 downvotes, ok, now, I gave a +1, but I do not really think your question deserves this negativity. You were asking an honest question, and even if it is duplicate, it makes nervous to see this from the community. I simply cannot understand why questions like these or even bugreports are sometimes downvoted to oblivion without any valid reason.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297639/why-doesnt-meta-stack-overflow-have-actual-reputation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because now Meta Stack Overflow is a "child meta" just like the child metas of every other site (e.g., Meta Super User, Meta Server Fault, etc.) On a child meta, your reputation is the same as on the "parent" site (excepting a minor delay for the numbers to sync up).

The site that *was* Meta Stack Overflow, and got treated like a "main" site, has been renamed/reskinned as [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Please see:

- [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)
- [Announcing the launch of Meta Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)

This has been in the works a long time. If you want more historical background there's also:

- [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)
- [Stack Overflow is getting a Meta of its own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)