# Why doesn't Meta Stack Overflow have real reputation?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, reputation, meta

Why isn't there real reputation on Meta Stack Overflow (MSO)?

It doesn't really make sense for a user's reputation on MSO to be the exact same as their reputation on Stack Overflow (SO), as these sites are fundamentally different. SO is a "question-and-answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers," while MSO is a question-and-answer site *about the SO site itself.*

Just because someone is an expert programmer doesn't necessarily mean they're also good with topics regarding the actual website, and just because someone doesn't have very much reputation on SO doesn't necessarily mean they shouldn't have a say in how the site works.

I suggest a change to the reputation system of MSO. Reputation shouldn't be mirrored from the parent site. Users should be able to gain and lose reputation normally, starting from 1.

MSO having its own reputation system independent of SO would also allow for useful features such as bounties.

I guess there must be a good reason why the reputation system on child metas were built the way they are. What's the reason for it?

Comment: To what purpose? I could see this making sense if we had problems with low participation rates on meta, but I haven't seen anything to indicate that. What are we trying to incentivize here? Is this just coming from a (misplaced, in my opinion) sense of "fairness"?

Comment: Then you would also have to lose reputation when a post gets downvoted and that is a bad idea since voting works differently on meta.

Comment: You're taking reputation way too seriously in general, not just here on Meta. Then again, your username does contain *Games* :)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see that your profile blurb is about getting the Autobiographer badge. Are you sure the gamification features of Stack Exchange do not count a little too much to you?

Comment: Looking at the popularity of your suggestions and the tone of your interactions, I'm not sure you're really *getting* Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should spend a little more time lurking before continuing to participate so actively in Meta?

Comment: All I want back from meta is the summary of upvotes and downvotes similar to how you get a summary of reputation on main sites. I just want to see how activity is faring in the long run. I don't think we need reputation to accomplish this, just some indication of voting aside from sorting by votes and manual inspection.

Comment: You do realize that the individual you claim deserves rep from that is a Stack Exchange employee and doesn't need the rep.

Comment: Your obsession with the fake internet points is getting a tad ridiculous, imho

Comment: i would think you would be counting your blessings that SO.Meta *doesn't* give/take rep. otherwise every point of rep you'll ever earn in SO will just be eaten by your flood of questions here on SO.Meta

Comment: Ah but there is reputation consequence on meta: someone will ask `why is my (insert bad question here) being downvoted?` and we'll all see this bad question that might have otherwise escaped being noticed and down vote it even more.  Like this one of yours for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592903/how-to-not-evaluate-a-variable-as-soon-as-its-defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Zizouz212's answer, but I feel a more important reason for the lack of reputation on meta is to encourages constructive debate.

I recently posted two answers on meta that I knew were going to attract a certain number of downvotes (I've been around for a while, so I know what's likely to be controversial); one of them turned out to be quite unpopular and currently sits at +15/-55 votes.

That's okay! Sometimes reasonable people don't always agree. And what's more, even if you fully disagree with my downvoted answer, it *still* provides value as it serves to emphasize the meta consensus, and it also provides a discussion about it in the comments.

This is why I haven't deleted this answer, and have no plans to do so.

---

If meta would have reputation, then these downvotes would come with real penalties, and I don't think that's a good thing if we want to encourage open and constructive discussions. I'm personally not overly worried about reputation (I've got plenty to spare), and in my specific example I would still come out on top reputation-wise (net gain of +40), but many other people are more sensitive to reputation and votes.
The end-result would be in people avoiding "controversial" answers, and instead posting only "popular" answers, to get more points.

While I'm not aware of any published studies on the subject, I feel that this effect is real on many sites which include prominent up/downvote systems such as Stack Overflow, reddit, Ars Technica comments, etc, even without any overarching "points system" such as reputation. People like being popular.

---

For this reason I feel that having reputation on meta.stack**exchange**.com is a mistake.

Answer (score 14):

But reputation means nothing on Stack Overflow. Reputation should mean your level of trust, of expertise, that is decided by the community itself. With meta, it doesn't work. You can't have an amazing or really horrible opinion. People can't judge you for suggesting something.

People participate on Meta because they are a part of the community, and they motivate themselves to contribute and improve to it.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. But what about MSE? I suggested something that would solve problems, but I got 50+ total down-votes, slapped with a question ban.

Comment: @NarawaGames But looking at your profile, all of your down voted questions are duplicates, and mods have complained that they are not thought out, or clear.

Comment: Duplicates, because the similar questions don't have any answers that help me, and my question isn't so different from the other ones. I just want to get helpful answers on those that don't.

Comment: Well, that's not what the community thought then. Even for one of your feature requests, no one got what the feature request was.

Answer (score -1):

In the beginning, there was [no meta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/28/cmon-get-meta/).

And the user's said "We want to talk about stackoverflow on stackoverflow"

And from stackoverflow, came three and one meta for all

And then there were many, [each with their own metas.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/22/new-per-site-metas/)

And at some point someone went "Yanno, it seems *odd* to have MSO differerent from everywhere else, and yet this works" so MSO became MSE, and MSO was created like the rest of the metas.

So... Any per site meta would have no reputation. It allows users to talk about the site with little fear of downvotes - and downvotes/upvotes work differently as far as site culture goes (agreement/disagreement)

MSE is a pretty darned useful relic of when we didn't have any per site metas, and acts as a place for *network wide issues*. And since it has no parent site, its special, different and has reputation (and its own odd way of doing things).
MSE is an outlier.

Comment: "In the beginning, there was no meta." False. There was unicorns and waffles.